# get_the_terms has strange result since version 6.0

Tags: wp-query, categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Since version 6.0 of WordPress some of my code with `get_the_terms()` doesn't work as expected in several sites where I use custom query loops.

For example I have this loop where I want to get the categories per post:

```
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'post_type' => 'post',
);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);

if ($posts->have_posts()) {
  while ($posts->have_posts()) { 
    $posts->the_post();
    $categories = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category');
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($categories, true) . '</pre>';
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Before 6.0 this was working fine. Now I get that the first post returns every category from all posts of this loop (including multiple instances of the same category), and all other posts return an empty array.

In this case I can also use `get_the_category()`, which has the same result. What am I doing wrong here? Or what should be the correct code since this new version of WordPress?

Comment: You’re using `$post->ID` but you haven’t actually defined it. Try `get_the_ID()` instead. Does that work?

Comment: Ah yes it should be `get_the_ID()`, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I don't see anything else wrong with the code as written. Is this the actual code that's casing you trouble?

Comment: Yes, but after searching further, I found out that this problem is coming from the WPML plugin. So I should ask this question at the WPML forum instead of here, I guess.

Comment: The plugin probably modified the behaviour to gets terms of the right language or something, so yeah you’d need to ask them what exactly might be happening.